# Burninate [conversion-function]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[conversion-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conversion-function) has five questions and no followers. All of the questions are C++ related. Notably, none of the questions tagged with it have a positive score.

Edit: I guess what I would suggest is, to fold them in with [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion) or just remove the tag, in most cases.

Burninate?

Comment: Most of them seem to be asking about [tag:conversion-operator].

Comment: Yes that is true, that is a bit more specific than [tag:type-conversion]

Comment: It's empty now, it should be removed when the empty tag removal script runs at UTC 3. That will stop it from being created again by users with less than 1500 reputation points.